# Which PDO SQL Server drivers do I use for FreeBSD?

Tags: php, freebsd, sqlsrv

Our systems administrator is no longer with our organization and I'm trying to take over managing a PHP Laravel project that has a MS SQL Server database.

I see that Microsoft has driver extensions available for various operating systems, but I'm a little confused because our server is FreeBSD.

I can't do the PECL install, so I'm guessing I have to copy the extensions to the appropriate directory manually and then add the extension reference to the php.ini file.

I'm just not sure what drivers I'm supposed to use from this list:

https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/v5.6.0

CentOS7
Debian8
Debian9
Mac
Suse12
Suse15
Ubuntu16
Ubuntu18
Ubuntu1810
Windows

I'm guessing its one of the Ubuntu ones, but I don't know how to ensure that I have selected the correct one.

Comment: FreeBSD is not Linux; if those are your only options you'll have to build from source.

Comment: Your question boils down to "how do I install stuff on FreeBSD". Firstly, that should give you an improved way to search for help. Secondly, a programming forum is not the right place, since this is about administration. BTW: 5.6.0? If that's really the version of PHP installed, you have other, serious problems. In any case, you have them, in particular if the system is exposed to the internet. Escalate this issue to management, if you don't know FreeBSD you can't solve it.

Comment: okay thank you for the clarification. I will vote to close this question.

Comment: For future posterity, the 5.6.0 is the version of Microsoft's Drivers, not the PHP version. Microsoft's Drivers v5.6.0 includes drivers for PHP v7.3. The do offer the source code as an option as well, so I may have to figure out how to compile it myself. Unfortunately, I can't just "escalate to management" because we are in a situation where we have no option but to try.